# Async HTTP Request with callback block in standard iOS classes similar to ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, objective-c-blocks, nsurlrequest

I find using blocks in some cases more convenient to use than the Delegate approach. I have been using [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) which provides [blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html) as a callback mechanism.

I was wondering if the standard Apple libraries provide the same technique for HTTP communication on iOS4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they don't. [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) works with delegation.

Comment: You're right, thanks. I figured out that blocks are available for this on the Mac (See my answer). Hopefully this will be available on iOS too soon.

Comment: iOS 5 supports it, but you asked for iOS 4

Answer (score 1):

Like erpayo correctly pointed out, `NSURLConnection` in iOS does not support blocks. However, it is possible with [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendAsynchronousRequest%3aqueue%3acompletionHandler%3a) on the Mac using the following method:

> #### sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:
>
> Loads the data for a URL request and executes a handler block on an operation queue
>   when the request completes or fails.
>
> ```
> + (void)sendAsynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request queue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse*, NSData*, NSError*))handler
> ```
>
> #### Parameters
>
> - request The URL request to load. The request object is deep-copied as part of the initialization process. Changes made to
>     request after this method returns do not affect the request that is
>     used for the loading process.
> - queue The operation queue to which the
>     handler block is dispatched when the request completes or failed.
> - handler The handler block to execute.
>
> #### Discussion
>
> If the request completes successfully, the data parameter of the handler block contains the resource data, and the
>   error parameter is nil. If the request fails, the data parameter is
>   nil and the error parameter contain information about the failure.
>
> #### Availability
>
> Available in Mac OS X v10.7 and later.
>
> #### Declared In
>
> `NSURLConnection.h`